# Make function always available, without calling it

Tags: angularjs

I want to validate max number of checked checkboxes.
I have this function and it works.

```
$('.Item:input').each(  function (i, element) {
    $(element).click(function() {      
      if ($('.Item:checked').length > 10) {        
        alert('error');
        $(element).attr('checked', false)
      }    
    })  
  });
```

Now i don't know how and where to call it in angular. I suppose to call it on ng-click event, but it works (obviously) only on the second click (first one only call the function)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: can you show it on jsfiddle?

Comment: There isn't an error on code. The problem is how a fuction can be always available without call it on event like ng-click

Comment: @EthanHunt You should probably inspect what is a controller in angular. Angular is not a replacement for jquery, it provides an architecture.

Comment: @sulthan: i know it... but i need a jquery function for this feature. Sorry for my question

Comment: @EthanHunt No, I meant that angular is giving you controllers. Use them - put the code you need inside them.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using data-ng-init instead of ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

`$viewContentLoaded` event is emitted that means to receive this event you need a parent controller like:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

From MainCtrl you can listen the event

```
 $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
//Here your view content is fully loaded !!
 });
```

Check the [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/isbTireh3w9OomDOvx87?p=preview).

I think this might solve your problem, or at least take you nearer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is for jquery, for angular approach is completly diffrent.

I have put an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/neolivz/8x15o1t4/

You can set up a model

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="test.value" ng-change ="updateCount(test)">
```

and do what you want in the `updateCount` api

```
 $scope.updateCount = function(test){
        if(test.value){
            $scope.count++;
        }else{
            $scope.count--;
        }
        if($scope.count==10){
            test.value = false;
            $scope.count--;
            return;     
        }
    }
```